# Finding a filename with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a Powershell script.

```
$baseFolder = "i:\MyClient\Data\"
$importFolder = "$baseFolder" + "_Import\"

$importFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $importFolder -filter "*.csv"

if (( $importFiles | Measure-Object ).Count -ne 1 ) {
    echo "ERROR: **** Incorrect usage **** "
    echo ""
    echo "The import folder: " $importFolder " must contain 1, and only 1 CSV file for importing."
} else {
    echo "Found 1 file for importing."

    #Do the import
}
```

It checks for 1 CSV file being in the _import folder.

There should only be 1 import file in the folder at a time. This is by design.

The filename can be anything.

I cannot figure out how I can get that filename from `Get-ChildItem` into a string so that I can append it to the $baseFolder + $archiveFolder variable (not shown), and move it later on.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the `-Name` parameter.

```
$importFileName = Get-ChildItem -Path $importFolder -filter "*.csv" -Name
```